# Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue laravel localhost on mac

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

I created the virtual host in XAMMP and i got this message from firefox

> Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to loginsite.dev because this website requires a secure connection.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use the `.dev` TLD anymore, it is [owned by Google](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) and they have pushed browser changes that break usage of `.dev` by requiring an SSL certificate.

They do this via an [Strict-Transport-Security Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) preloaded for `.dev`.

Instead, you should use the `.local` TLD for you local development.